# Why I am getting a Heap Corruption Error?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am new to C++. I am getting HEAP CORRUPTION ERROR. Any help will be highly appreciated. Below is my code

```
class CEntity  
{  
//some member variables  
CEntity(string section1,string section2);  
CEntity();  
virtual ~CEntity();  
//pure virtual function ..  
virtual CEntity* create()const = 0;  
};
```

I derive CLine from CEntity as below

```
class CLine:public CEntity  
{  
// Again some variables ...  
// Constructor and destructor  
CLine(string section1,string section2);  
CLine();  
~CLine();  
CLine* Create() const;  
}  

// CLine Implementation  
CLine::CLine(string section1,string section2) : CEntity(section1,section2){};  
CLine::CLine();  
CLine* CLine::create() const {return new CLine();}
```

I have another class CReader which uses CLine object and populates it in a multimap  as below

```
class CReader  
{  
public:  
CReader();  
~CReader();  
multimap<int,CEntity*>m_data_vs_entity;  
};  

//CReader Implementation  
CReader::CReader()  
{  
  m_data_vs_entity.clear();  
};  

CReader::~CReader()  
{  
  multimap<int,CEntity*>::iterator iter;  
  for(iter = m_data_vs_entity.begin();iter!=m_data_vs_entity.end();iter++)  
  {  
    CEntity* current_entity = iter->second;  
    if(current_entity)  
      delete current_entity;  
  }  
  m_data_vs_entity.clear();  
}
```

I am reading the data from a file and then populating the CLine Class.The map gets populated in a function of CReader class. Since CEntity has a virtual destructor, I hope the piece of code in CReader's destructor should work. In fact, it does work for small files but I get HEAP CORRUPTION ERROR while working with bigger files. If there is something fundamentally wrong, then, please help me find it, as I have been scratching my head for quit some time now.
Thanks in advance and awaiting reply,
Regards,
Atul

Continued from Y'day : 
Further studying this in detail I now have realized that Heap allocation error in my case is because I am allocating something, and then overwriting it with a higher size.
Below is the code where in my data gets populated in the constructor.

```
CEntity::CEntity(string section1,string section2)
{
    size_t length;
    char buffer[9];
    //Entity Type Number
    length = section1.copy(buffer,8,0);
    buffer[length]='\0';
    m_entity_type = atoi(buffer);

    //Parameter Data Count
    length = section1.copy(buffer,8,8);
    buffer[length]='\0';
    m_param_data_pointer = atoi(buffer);
        //.... like wise ....
}
```

I am getting the values at a fixed interval of 8 chars and I am adding a '\0' so this, i guess will take care of any garbage value that I encounter.

About 
**Heap allocation error: after normal block (XXX) at XXX, CRT detected that application wrote to memory after end of Heap buffer.** Mostly, Heap allocation errors occur somewhere else than where it crashes. I would appreciate if some one here would help me, how to make use of this normal block and the address.
Thanks,

Comment: is it actual code ? if so why `create` is a non-static member function? how is it supposed to be used?

Comment: also can you show us the code which populates `m_data_vs_entity` as I have a feeling that you might be putting the same pointer twice into the map.

Comment: @Naveen, I think his `create()` is an example of the virtual constructor idiom -- it's not supposed to be static.

Comment: @Poita_: Yeah, you are right. I forgot that.

Comment: bool CReader::process_entity(string section1,string section2)
{
size_t length;
char buffer[9];
//1.Entity Type Number
length = Section1.copy(buffer,8,0);
buffer[length]='\0';
int ent_type = atoi(buffer);
CEntity* current_ent = NULL;
switch(ent_type)
{
case 110: 
CLine* line_entity = new CLine(Section1,Section2);
current_ent = line_entity;
break;
default:
{
   break;
}
}
if(current_ent != NULL)
{
int PD_Pointer = current_ent->get_parameter_data_ptr();
// Populating the maps and multimaps for linkages ...
m_data_vs_entity.insert(pair<int,CEntity*>(PD_Pointer,current_ent));
}
return true;
}

Comment: @Atul Don't post the code as a comment - edit it into your question, and format it properly.

Comment: m_param_data_pointer = atoi(buffer);  - That line sends shivers down my spine - Please tell me you're not writing pointers out to a file/database/socket and then reading them back in later??

Comment: :), Nope, that pointer is not what C, C++ pointer is, in a conventional sense. It's just the name of my variable, as it points to something. BTW, it's an integer. And again, it does not store any address ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after two days of debugging, I was able to fix up the crash. It was due to me copying wrong number of characters from the string.
Lessons learnt :
1. When you encounter memory allocation errors, try to form a simple test case which has minimum entities to reproduce the problem.
2. A sure shot way is a line by line debugging. I agree,it test your patience, but then, there are no short cuts to success
3. And it gives you a chance to do a code review, further enhancing the quality of code that you produce in future

Thank you for all your help and formatting my code :)
Regards,
Atul

Comment: @Atul One more bit of advice. Do not post additions to your question, extra code, explanations etc. as answers - edit them into your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're only showing half the problem.

Where's the code that creates the CLine objects and stores them in the CReader?

Also, what do you consider actually "owns" the CEntity objects? Generally, you should make the 'owner' responsible for creation as well as deletion...

I wrote earlier:

> "You might like to consider storing
>   the CEntitys directly in the map,
>   rather than storing pointers.
>   Potentially less efficient, but also
>   much less scope for cockups."

As Neil points out, it's not CEntities that you will be storing, so that suggestion isn't going to help you much...

Comment: He can't store CEntities in anything - it's an abstract class.

Comment: The capital C is probably only a typo, don't you think?

Comment: @ Roddy: Meaning, instead of the multimap <int,CEntity*>, I should have a multimap of <int,void*>, and I should directly store the inherited entities that is CLine etc ?

Comment: @Atul, No, I meant multimap<int, CEntity>. But I hadn't appreciated the polymorphic nature of the problem, so it won't work exactly like that.

Comment: Further research on this lead me to the revelation that I am allocating